# keras, model still setting expected input shape from training despite input_shape(None, ...)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a simple CNN model written in the tf.keras framework, which I wish to use with variable input size.

According to [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1920#issuecomment-193883690) "documentation" I can use variable input size by setting `input_shape=(None, None, n_channels)`, and I have used a `GlobalMaxPooling2D` layer before my dense layer to standardize the input to the dense layer.

Yet when I train the model with one size of image and try to predict on a different size I get the error:

```
  File "multilabel_384.py", line 180, in main
probabilities = model.predict(test_data)
File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/deepchem/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1471, in predict
x, check_steps=True, steps_name='steps', steps=steps)
File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/deepchem/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 868, in _standardize_user_data
exception_prefix='input')
File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/deepchem/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 191, in standardize_input_data
' but got array with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected sequential_input to have shape (16, 24, 1) but got array with shape (32, 48, 1)
```

This is the code used to define my model:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf

def make_model(num_classes=8):
    # type (int) -> tf.keras.model
    """implementation of SimpleNet in keras"""
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    # conv layers
    model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D(2))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(input_shape=(None, None, 1),
                            filters=32, kernel_size=5, activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D(2))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=64,  kernel_size=5, activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D())
    # dense layers
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))
    # use sigmoid for multiclass problems
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="sigmoid"))
    return model
```

So in essence my question is why is keras *still* defining an expected input shape, and is there any way to disable this implicit `standardize_input_data` that's going on?

Comment: The input shape should go in the first layer of the model, but it isn't in your case.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro You're right, if you could post it as an answer I'll accept. Why zero padding isn't part of Conv2D is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input shape should be in the first layer of your model, but you are putting it in the second. So Keras is assuming a shape from your training data.